# Objects missing from Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Alright, I'm going crazy trying to figure this one out, so I figured I'd post it and see if anyone knew what was going on.

I add entities to Core Data and retrieve them fine and everything displays perfectly in my app. But for some reason when I use `NSFetchRequest` to get a list of all the entities of some type, it always returns one less object than there should be. I know the object is somewhere because my app can display data from it elsewhere in the app. Also, I manually examined the sqlite file and noticed that it is also missing one object. How is this possible if my app is accessing the data?

Here's the code I use to fetch the entities. I use this code in many places throughout my app and it always returns one less object then there really is, but my app is still about to access it.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MWLocationItem" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on? Please let me know if there's any other code you'd like to see.

Comment: When you say you can view the data elsewhere, where are you talking about? The easiest way to view the data in your persistant store (assuming you're using the default SQLite store) is to use a SQL lite viewer

Comment: How are you verifying that it has one less object? fetchedObjects.count?

Comment: Yes. In some places in my app it will return the correct number and then in other places it returns one less. And manually inspecting the sqlite file shows that one object is missing.

Comment: I did manually view the sqlite file. I said that in my question.

Comment: It looks like the first object I add is the one that's "missing." What could cause it to not appear in the sqlite file?

Comment: Hmm..I added another `[NSManagedObjectContext save:]` and that seems to have fixed it even though I was saving later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** I think that this is can be possible if you're ignoring error's on

```
[NSManagedObjectContext save:nil]
```

Try to use method below, to check if is everything okay

```
[NSManagedObjectContext save:&error]
```

**2.** Another possible reason can be that you set includesPendingChanges property to fetchrequest

```
request.includesPendingChanges = NO;
```

If there's no correct answer :) Can you provide a bit more lines of source code?

Comment: The problem was just that I had to add another save call in there somewhere. It seems to be working now.